# I gave two arguments to this function, it says I only gave one

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this very basic question on Coursera (Python):

> 1. Write two functions, one called addit and one called mult. addit takes one number as an input and adds 5. mult takes one number as an
>      input, and multiplies that input by whatever is returned by addit, and
>      then returns the result.

**My attempt:**

```
def mult(x,y):
    return x*addit(y)


def addit(x):
    return x+5
```

> **The error message:**
>
> ERROR None    None    Error: TypeError: mult() takes exactly 2 arguments (1
>   given)
>
> Pass  6   6   Testing the function addit with input 1 (should be 6)
>
> Pass  3   3   Testing the function addit with input -2 (should be 3)
>
> Pass  5   5   Testing the function addit with input 0 (should be 5)

so it passed to all tests but there is an error message saying "TypeError: mult() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)".

I really don't understand, I gave two arguments "x" and "y" in mult function.

Comment: "I gave two arguments "x" and "y" in mult function." No; you gave two *parameters* to `mult`. Nothing in your own code *calls* `mult`; that's what the test code does. The test code only provides one argument, so you must only have one parameter.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly your problem: the assignment clearly specifies that `mult` is to take only one argument.  Fix your function and try again.

```
" mult takes one number as an input, ..."
```

Comment: you got it!!!!!

Comment: so I'm hopeless here, do you have a hint?

Comment: haaa ok, I got it, another reading comprehension. Thank you

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  That middle comment above is *seriously* out of scope for Stack Overflow.